# PHP returns “unexpected semicolon” error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website where you can sign up for a handball team by filling out a form (simple school project). I want to check whether this form has been filled out or not by using isset. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    require("mysql.php");
    if(isset($_GET['submit']{ 
        db_koble_til("localhost", "root", "", "handball");
        ...
        ...
```

The problem is though, I get an error after the if statement on the fourth line. When I run the site, it says there's an unexpected semicolon there. What do I do to fix this? My php knowledge is very limited as you probably can tell.

Comment: Whops, used the wrong title, this was from an earlier question

Comment: You can change it. Click on “edit” below tag list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgot about ")" sign

```
<?php
require("mysql.php");
if(isset($_GET['submit'] )) { 
    db_koble_til("localhost", "root", "", "handball");
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really clumsy of me not to notice before asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    // Every parenthesis opened should be followed by a closing parenthesis.
}
```